# Trying to view my localhost on my ipad so I don't have to deploy a website first

Tags: iphone, ipad, localhost

Ok,so this might be an odd question for this forum, but I can't find anything on it anywhere. I am new to web development, I've been at it for about 6 months and I'm slowly getting better. I create localhosts on my comp to view the look of my development for any website I'm building, this way I can see how the site reacts in a real-world setting. I'm positive that most developers do this. What I would like to know is if there is a way to connect an iPad or iPhone to that particular localhost so I can view how responsive my website is before I deploy it? There's got to be some way to view your developing website on a mobile device, I just have no clue on how to do that. So, if anyone is familiar with this, I would really appreciate some advice. Thanks, guys!!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I assume that your iPad and computer are connecting to the same wireless router. The IP of your PC and iPad should both start with 192.168.*.*. Then viewing your localhost site on iPad is absolutely possible.
e.g 
If your localhost site is on the PC with IP of 192.168.0.100 with port:8080, you can connect this site on iPad through url: `http://192.168.0.100:8080`

Comment: Hey, I appreciate the help, and this might sound really stupid, but where do I find what the IP of my localhost is? I tried ifconfig in the terminal also man ifconfig, but I'm not sure what I'm looking for. I've had a huge learning curve because I didn't really know computers when I started coding. Anyways, I appreciate you answering , thanks so much. Cheers!

Comment: @ajmatic check this link [How to Find the IP Address of Your PC](http://www.wikihow.com/Find-the-IP-Address-of-Your-PC)

Comment: I appreciate the help, I need to get a little more familiar with things.

Comment: I was pushing to heroku and then checking the preview! Thanks a lot! :D :D

Answer (score 10):

If using Mac for a Rails app.

1. In terminal Ctrl-C to shut down previous server
2. Go into your System Preferences on your mac, then "Network". Under connected you will "Wi-Fi is connected to _____________  and has the IP address 192.XXX.X.XX."
3. Go to terminal, type `rails s --binding=192.XXX.X.XX` <-- use your IP not Xs
4. In the browser address bar on your Ipad type `http://192.XXX.X.XX:3000`

Comment: Works perfectly for iPhone, too!

Answer (score 1):

I created a bash function in my `.bashrc` (or `.zshrc`) file to do just that:

```sh
##
# Bind local server to port to view on mobile device!
# usage (from root location): `railsipserver 3100` (any preferred port)
##
railsipserver() {
  REQUIRED_ARGS_NUMBER="1"

  if [ "$#" -lt "$REQUIRED_ARGS_NUMBER" ]; then
    echo 1>&2 "$0: not enough arguments"
    return
  elif [ "$#" -gt "$REQUIRED_ARGS_NUMBER" ]; then
    echo 1>&2 "$0: too many arguments"
    return
  fi

  PORT=$1
  IP_ADDRESS=$(ifconfig | grep "inet " | grep -v 127.0.0.1 | cut -d\  -f2)
  PID="1$PORT" # needs to be unique to run multiple servers from same location

  echo ""
  echo "~~~~~"
  echo "Your server is starting now!"
  echo "View on external device (phone or iPad) at..."
  echo "http://$IP_ADDRESS/$PORT"
  echo "~~~~~"
  echo ""

  rails server --port $PORT --binding "$IP_ADDRESS" --pid $PID
}
```

I also created these aliases to run so i can view the same site on my local machine (with `localhost:3000`) AND simultaneously on my iPad (with `http://192.168.X.X:3100`).

```sh
alias mydir="path/to/my-site-directory"
alias myserver="cd mydir && rails server --port 3000
alias myipserver="cd mydir && railsipserver 3100
```

So I simply open two tabs in Terminal (or iTerm) and type

Tab 1: `myserver`

Tab 2: `myipserver`

Voila!  I can view all my local changes on my computer AND on my iPad!